# Data model and markup for planning calendar using bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-5, data-modeling

I'm building an application that will display some sort of calendar to visualize the planning for our different departments. This is a mockup of what it should look like:

[image]

There will be 21 days displayed. Every day can have several of these colored cards. Each card represents a planned task. **Some tasks can span multiple days!**
I'm doubting if I should do this using bootstraps grid system or with a table. I am also trying to come up with a suitable datamodel that the api should return so the UI can build up the markup easily.